# How to rotate an image in all the direction using css

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sass

I have an image which is basically is on overlay and I want to rotate the image in all the directions using css and vue js.

I have a codepen written by me which will help you understand of what I am doing and below I have posted the code

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-xs-center image-rotation" :class="{rotateImageRight: right, rotateImageLeft: left }">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
    </div>
    <v-btn @click="rotateRight"> rotate right </v-btn>
    <v-btn @click="rotateLeft"> rotate left </v-btn>

  </v-app>
</div>
```

Below is the css I am using

```
.image-rotation {
  &.rotateImageRight {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
  }
  &.rotateImageLeft {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}
```

And finally my vuejs code

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      right: false,
      left: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
   rotateRight() {
     this.right = !this.right
   },
    rotateLeft() {
      this.left = !this.left
    }
  }
})
```

Below is my code pen link

https://codepen.io/waseem-khan-the-bold/pen/RmrZNY

Answer (score 8):

I think that the best way to do this is to directly apply your rotation to a bound style tag. See below for an example

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      rotation: 0,
    }
  },
  methods: {
   rotateRight() {
     this.rotation -= 90
   },
    rotateLeft() {
     this.rotation += 90
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-xs-center" :style="`transform: rotate(${rotation}deg);`">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
    </div>
    <v-btn @click="rotateLeft"> rotate left </v-btn>
    <v-btn @click="rotateRight"> rotate right </v-btn>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Or codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ardLdQ

Comment: If this answers your question please accept the answer as such by clicking that checkmark  on the left side :)